# Delayed jump to a new web page

Tags: javascript, html

How do I cause the page to make the user jump to a new web page after X seconds. If possible I'd like to use HTML but a niggly feeling tells me it'll have to be Javascript.

So far I have the following but it has no time delay

```
<body onload="document.location='newPage.html'">
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A meta refresh is ugly but will work.  The following will go to the new url after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/"/>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: This really is the best - no JavaScript needed, so it will work just about anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going the JS route just use

```
setTimeout("window.location.href = 'newPage.html';", 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this is in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=newPage.html">
```

This will redirect after 5 seconds. Make 0 to redirect onload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use good ole' [META REFRESH](http://webmaster.indiana.edu/tool_guide_info/refresh_metatag.shtml), no JS required, although those are (I think) deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The Meta Refresh is the way to go, but here is the JavaScript solution:

```
<body onload="setTimeout('window.location = \'newpage.html\'', 5000)">
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript method, without invoking `eval` in the the `setTimeout`:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='newpage.html'}, 5000)">
```